# Merging items of array of object if they have equal keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

### Array of objects that I got

```
  [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "price": 100
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "price": 80
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "price": 8
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "price": 85
    }
  ]
```

### Array of objects that I am trying to do

```
  [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "price": 88.33 // AVERAGE VALUE BETWEEN DUPLICATED OBJECTS
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "price": 8
    }
  ]
```

I am merging and getting the ***average price for duplicated objects***.

### What I have done:

I have tried to use `filter()` function but I removed the duplicated without merging the prices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid extra loops and extra properties is not a problem, you can use a getter for each object as follow:

You can use the function `Array.prototype.reduce` for grouping objects by `id` and the function `Object.values` for extracting the grouped values.

The getter `price` calculates the average when this property is accessed.

**Extra properties:**

```
{
    count: Integer // count of repeated ids.
    sum: Double // total sum of prices
}
```

```js
const arr = [    {      "id": 1,      "price": 100    },    {      "id": 1,      "price": 80    },    {      "id": 2,      "price": 8    },    {      "id": 1,      "price": 85    }  ],
      result = Object.values(arr.reduce((r, {id, price}) => {
        let current = (r[id] || (r[id] = {id, sum: 0, count: 0, get price() {
          return this.sum / this.count;
        }}));

        current.sum += price;
        current.count++;

        return r;
      }, {}));

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: problem is that I have quantity and other keys and values in my object but I didnt want to make the json big in my question...

Comment: I have took your answer and added quantity in the params and it worked!

Comment: @Jaad great, so, the extra properties are not invasive.

Comment: Is that a good solution that I have done? what do you mean by invasive

Comment: @Jaad I didn't get it. Can you share the solution where `quantity` is involved?

Comment: `
let current = (r[id] || (r[id] = {id, get quantity() {
 return quantity + 2;
}, sum: 0, count: 0, get price() {
return this.sum / this.count;
}}));
`
check this please

Comment: @Jaad yeah, it's ok, the weird thing is that `+ 2` I don't understand.

Comment: I was just testing something to make sure i can edit the quantity :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with an ES6 [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). By using `reduce()` you can accumulate all objects into a Map, where the key is the `id` from the object and the value is an accumulated array of `price` values for the given `id`. You can then convert the `Map` back into an array using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), where you can provide a mapping function to convert the `[key, value]` pairs from the map into an object. The object's `price` key will be the sum of all numbers in the `value` array (`arr`) divided by the length of the array, which will give you the average.

See example below:

```js
const arr = [ { "id": 1, "price": 100 }, { "id": 1, "price": 80 }, { "id": 2, "price": 8 }, { "id": 1, "price": 85 } ];

const res = Array.from(arr.reduce((m, {id, price}) => {
  return m.set(id, [...(m.get(id) || []), price]);
}, new Map), ([id, arr]) => ({id, price: arr.reduce((t, n) => t+n, 0) / arr.length}));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Will that solution will work fine if I have another keys in my objects?

Answer (score 0):

Use `forEach` loop and build an object with keys as `id` and aggregate price.
Use `Object.values` of above object and calculate the averages.

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    price: 100,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    price: 80,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    price: 8,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    price: 85,
  },
];

const process = (arr) => {
  const res = {};
  arr.forEach(({ id, price }) => {
    res[id] ??= { id, sum: 0, count: 0 };
    res[id].sum += price;
    res[id].count += 1;
  });
  return Object.values(res).map(({ id, sum, count }) => ({
    id,
    price: sum / count,
  }));
};

console.log(process(data));
```